# Background Image in ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I being trying to attach a to attach an image to a background, and it wont display.

my current code path is assets > stylesheets > application.css and assets > stylesheets > style.css.scss

Whats the correct url path my current code is as follow:

```
background: #F4F4F4 url("/assets/images/background.jpg");
```

I been looking around but none of the solution has been working your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one please

```
background: #F4F4F4 url("background.jpg")
```

Comment: The reason this worked because, the Rails would search for its assets in three places irrespective of the location of them in any folder. This means that if you any image placed under CSS or JavaScripts folder then if you want to use it, you simply have to write the name of the file.